# Yammer API to get unread message count

Tags: c#, rest, yammer

I want to get the count for Yammer Inbox's unread messages using the yammer REST API.

The documented messages are provided here: https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-messages

But unfortunately, I cannot find the unread count anywhere. Is there a specific tag in the response that provides this count?

Any help here is appreciated.

**Update**:
By unread count, I mean a count of messages that haven't been checked yet. The yammer inbox tab shows this count. (See image at this link for reference. http://picpaste.com/pics/d-swJKH732.1393307190.png)

Comment: Define "unread". If it's something like "all new messages received since the last read message", then store the last read message id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the above question to clarify what I was looking for. Isn't there a tag to support this unread message count?

Comment: I came here hunting for an answer to a related issue: this unread count is usually displayed wrongly for me when I have no unread messages.   Just letting you know that it's probably buggy, even if you do get access to it... google will tell you that others have this problem as well.  http://status.yammer.com/page/3/